# How to navigate to different section in the same page using vuetify?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I tried the HTML way of doing it using anchors:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#dashobard">Dashboard</a></li>
</ul>
```

And my target is like:

```vue
<v-card id="dashboard">
  <v-card-text class="document">
    Contract Details: lorem ipsum ...
  </v-card-text>
</v-card>
```

But the problem is when I click on Dashboard link it goes to 2 lines after the title (in this case 'Contract Details').

I was wondering if there is a way of doing this using Vuetify. I could not find it in their documentation. I also tried `<v-card name="dashboard">` but it was the same results. I am new to Vue and Vuetify, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can using Vuetify: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/scroll

Comment: @8bit Thank you very much for your help. I got the same results though. It might be the way I am using it? <a @click="$vuetify.goTo('#dashboard')">Dashboard</a>

Comment: Maybe some margin or padding interference, can you try doing it on a plain div with, not a `v-card` or `v-card-text`

Comment: I removed the `v-card` and `v-card-text` and used div instead. Still, the same result

Comment: @8bit So I just realized something very weird. If I am on full-screen windows, it works but if I make the windows screen smaller(in width) then it causes the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out what the problem was. Since my `navbar` was fixed at the top and my content would hide underneath the `navbar`, all I had to do to use `offset: -60` in `options` and pass it like this:

```
<li><a @click="$vuetify.goTo('#dashboard',options)">dashboard</a></li>
```

My `navbar` was 64px in height.

Comment: Why does this not work if you are from another Route page? How do we prevent it from happening?

Comment: Because this is part of [Scrolling Directive](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/directives/scrolling).